# Oracle, Inserting correlative numbers based on other fields

Tags: sql, oracle, select, correlation

Sorry for my english:

My query `select date from mytable` returns something like this:

```
DATE

27/09/2011
27/09/2011
27/09/2011
27/09/2011
28/09/2011
28/09/2011
29/09/2011
29/09/2011
29/09/2011
```

I also need that my query returns a correlative based on each diferent date. something like...

```
DATE         | CORRELATIVE
             |
27/09/2011   | 1
27/09/2011   | 2
27/09/2011   | 3
27/09/2011   | 4
28/09/2011   | 1
28/09/2011   | 2
29/09/2011   | 1
29/09/2011   | 2
29/09/2011   | 3
```

I need help to get it, something like `select date, any_way_to_get_it from mytable`
thk!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's the function](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) you should use.

```
SELECT date, ROW_NUMBER()
   OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY date) AS any_way_to_get_it 
   FROM mytable;
```

Comment: Hello thk for your answer, I got that message: ORA-30485: missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification

Comment: As unnecessary as it sounds, you need an `order by` in the `over` clause to avoid `ORA-30485: missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification`.